# How to make a custom tab in Tabbar to display different color when selected

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I've been using this custom container to create the tab for the TabBar. I'd like the selected tab to display a different color than the unselected tabs. The '2nd' tab is an example of how the selected tab should be, but i've hard coded it to show as example.

```
TabBar(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    tabs: [
      Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFFF4F1F1),
          border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFFFAC5C5), width: 2),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
        ),
        child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('1st'),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xfffacdc9),
          border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFFFAC5C5), width: 2),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
        ),
        child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('2nd'),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFFF4F1F1),
          border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xfffccccc), width: 2),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
        ),
        child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('3rd'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I have tried to improvise using some indicator properties of Tabbar, but didn't work because it only shows as a shadow for the container instead of being the foreground color.

```
TabBar(indicator: 
   BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TabController` for catching `TabBar`'s current index, and changing that index.

```dart
class TabBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabBarExample> createState() => _TabBarExampleState();
}

class _TabBarExampleState extends State<TabBarExample>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // TODO: use this tabController for TabBar and TabBarView
  late final TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...,
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          ...,
          tabs: [
            Container(
              ...,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // catch if current tab index is 0
                color: _tabController.index == 0
                    ? const Color(0xFFFACDC9)
                    : const Color(0xFFF4F1F1),
                ...,
              ),
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // change current tab index to 0
                  setState(() {
                    _tabController.animateTo(0);
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('1st'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              ...,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _tabController.index == 1
                    ? const Color(0xFFFACDC9)
                    : const Color(0xFFF4F1F1),
                ...,
              ),
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _tabController.animateTo(1);
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('2nd'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              ...,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _tabController.index == 2
                    ? const Color(0xFFFACDC9)
                    : const Color(0xFFF4F1F1),
                ...,
              ),
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _tabController.animateTo(2);
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('3rd'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [...],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try the following
use Tabbar with tab as children

```
TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
          ],
        ),
```

additional the tabs can be customized to suit your design

Comment: Your answer won't display a different colour when selected. Please try to understand what the questioner is asking about. Your code only displays icons and nothing else. Neither colour nor selection is happening in your code.

Comment: Your answer won't display a different colour when selected. Please try to understand what the questioner is asking about. Your code only displays icons and nothing else. Neither colour nor selection is happening in your code.